# JavaScript won't work in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

So.. I have this javascript code and I tried to run it with an html tester and it worked fine (also with the tester on this site). Now when I try to use the exact same code on a wordpress page it doesn't. What's the matter? I don't get it. A very simple code however works (I tried an alert as suggested in an other thread).

So this is my code:

```html
<script>
function calc(){
var year = document.getElementById("dateinput").value;
var yearFormat = year.replace(".","");
var yearNumber = parseInt(yearFormat);

if(1011800 <= yearNumber && yearNumber <= 12121990){
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "One";
}else if(12121991 <= yearNumber && yearNumber <= 12122000){
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Two";
}else{
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Error";
}
}
</script>

<input id="dateinput"></input>
<button onClick="calc()">Submit</button>
</br>
Your result:<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Do you receive any errors in the console?

Comment: Where are you adding this code? To a plugin, functions.php, theme file, or a post?

Comment: Directly to a post. No errors from the console, just not working.

Comment: Are you pasting it in to the Visual or Text view?

Comment: In the text view of course.